# Can I use MySQL Workbench to create data?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

The MySQL Workbench seems to be a nice tool for create database schemata.

When I export a model, there is a checkbox for "create insert statements". Thus, it should have an option to fill one's tables with data, but I can't find it anywhere.

So how to add data to your tables in MySQL workbench? Or, what tools do you recommend for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you build your schema in MySQL and you either let the app using the database populate itself with data over time, or you'll be importing existing data from an existing system using some level of scripting or programming, possibly/probably an extension of whatever system will be using the database.

I suppose certain test cases may exist where you'd want to use Workbench to generate some data; or maybe you want to populate some lookup tables at schema creation, but I'd think there would be better/easier ways...Regardless, MySQL's official documentation for this is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor.html#wb-table-editor-inserts-tab).

Answer (score 7):

Two related answers:

Generally, you can edit data in the "Result Grid" in the SQL Editor. From the Schemas Navigator (left pane), right-click on a table and select "SELECT Rows - Limit 1000". This opens a "Result Grid" tab in the SQL Editor. Simply click the cells and add data. On the right you'll see that "Result Grid" is selected by default, and you can change it to "Form Editor" for another input method. Workbench 6.2 simplifies this by adding icons next to each table in the object navigator, including one to select all rows.

For Models, double click on a table (or, right-click on a table and choose "Edit Table"), then go to the "Inserts" tab (you'll see it near the bottom). This field editor is similar to the results grid editor mentioned above. After making your additions (inserting rows), click the checkbox next to "Apply". These entries will be added as a transaction.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: This exactly answers the question

Comment: Note that you can't do this if your table doesn't have a primary key see here for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815029/mysql-workbench-edit-table-data-is-read-only